# Add scrollbar to DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell, editablegrid

I wonder there are no posts on internet for this question, How do I add scrollbar to work on DataGridViewTextBoxColumn after MyGrid_EditingControlShowing event displays this textbox on grid.

I have added below event

```
private void MyGrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
if ((!(e.Control is TextBox)) || e.CellStyle.WrapMode == DataGridViewTriState.True) return;
            var textBox = e.Control as TextBox;
            textBox.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
}
```

but it didn't worked, when mouse scrolled it scrolled to grid's row not on cell

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
!(e.Control is TextBox))
```

will never be true.

You can try this instead:

```
if (MyGrid.CurrentCell.EditType != typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
{
    return;
}
```

Or this:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;

if (tb == null)
{
    return;
}
```

Note that the `ScrollBars` will still only show when the `Cell` is in edit mode! The ['Cells'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell?view=netframework-4.7.2) of a `DateGridView` are only **virtual** controls or, in other words, they are just **pixels** painted on the screen. They have no event model etc, so they can't function interactively. Only the `EditControl` that gets overlaid is an actual control.